# FormValidator doesn't validate selects with options changed via ajax callback

Tags: forms, 8

I have a custom form with 2 select fields, first (Country Select) has an ajax callback which when is triggered the options from second (Country Currency) callback are changed. Options are replaced in select list but on  submit or selecting another country the validation is not passed.

The error I get is on line #362 in FormValidator.php

> An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator.

```
  elseif (!isset($options[$elements['#value']])) {
    $form_state->setError($elements, $this->t('An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator.'));
    $this->logger->error('Illegal choice %choice in %name element.', array('%choice' => $elements['#value'], '%name' => empty($elements['#title']) ? $elements['#parents'][0] : $elements['#title']));
  }
```

Current options were changed but select is still keeping the value from previous options and \Drupal\Core\Form performRequiredValidation() method throws above error.

Any ideas how to fix/avoid this are welcome.